# Given that $y= 4x - 3$, work out the value of $x$ when $y = 11$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Given that $y= 4x - 3$, work out the value of $x$ when $y = 11$

I don't get this because i can't think of a number that you can multiply by 4 then subtract 3 to get 11 or am i missing something?

Comment: Your $x$ can be a rational number.

Comment: The object is not to guess the value of $x$ but to solve the equation $11=4x-3$ where the $y$ has been given the value of 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like a step by step solution:
So if $y=4x-3$ then add 3 to each side to get: $y+3=4x$.

Next just divide both sides by 4 to get $x = (y+3)\div4$.

Now the final step is to substitute your value of 11 in for $y$ which will give you $x = (11+3)\div4 = 3.5$

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve the equation:
$$11 = 4 x - 3.$$
Using the basic properties of equations you get 
$$x=\frac{11 + 3}{4}$$
i.e.
$$
x = 3.5.
$$

Comment: thanks alot i don't know why i didnt think of that